# Can I declare modules as globally available with Typescript?

Tags: typescript, backbone.js

I'm using TypeScript for a web app built with Backbone, Marionette, and Backbone Associations.

These libraries will be bundled and available everywhere using Webpack's ProvidePlugin, but to keep the TS compiler happy, I need to add the following to every module in my application:

```
import * as _ from "underscore";
import * as Backbone from "backbone";
import * as Marionette from "backbone.marionette";
import "backbone-associations";
```

This could potentially be hundreds of modules / files.

Is there anyway to tell TypeScript that these will be generally available? Perhaps some setting in tsconfig.json?

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the (e.g.) `underscore` typings. If you're using TS 2+ the compiler should pick up all typings inside `node_modules/@types/...`. You can also specify them yourself in the `typings` property of your `tsconfig.json`. [See the docs.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types)

[TypeScript tries to prevent you from mixing UMD and ES modules.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7125) It will show the following error:

```
"_" refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module.
Consider adding an import instead.
```

One way around this is to create a custom `.d.ts` file, you may call it `global.d.ts.` doesn't matter. Put it in your TS project and add the following:

```
import * as _ from 'underscore';

declare global {
  const _:_.UnderscoreStatic;
}
```

Now `underscore` should be globally available and you should also be able to mix UMD + ES `import`/`export` statements. [You can find more info about this in the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-modifying-module-d-ts.html).

Comment: I'm using TS 2.2.1, and all typings are in `node_modules/@types`, but I still get errors if I remove any of the above imports from a particular module. I thought maybe if the imports where in *any* file, they'd have to be in *all*. I'd like to know that before attempting to remove them all, because I have a huge number of modules.

Comment: You should add the errors you're getting to your question. Otherwise it is hard to guess what issue you're having, because it also depends on your TS configuration.